# wxPython is there a way to draw half circle

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

Question is simple is there a way to draw half circle or pie using *wxGraphicsContext*? I need to make something look like in the picture (this gauge 
is made in pyQt4).

[image]

EDIT: I did

```
    path = gc.CreatePath()
    path.AddArc(450, 100, 30, math.radians(180), math.radians(0))
    pen = wx.Pen('#ffffff', 1)
    #pen.SetCap(wx.CAP_BUTT)
    gc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#CC7F32', wx.SOLID))
    gc.SetPen(pen)
    gc.DrawPath(path)
```

and I got this

[image]

How can I get full outline because now there is none at the bottom of the arc?

Comment: Yes, you need to paint an *arc*...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried arc and what about draw pie?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was set brush to transparent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [AddArc()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_graphics_path.html#a42dfa8d02729f00b4171f2bf83e16dbe) or, probably better in this particular case, [AddArcToPoint()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_graphics_path.html#acb1c90212eb13f75d7a73a1444cbd852). As always, remember that you can fill any path by setting the brush corresponding to the desired background colour and calling [FillPath()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_graphics_context.html#a225c90d767a6c26989d85ac8463d029f) instead of just `StrokePath()`.

And to draw the segment, you should just call `AddLineToPoint()` directly: it's simple as you just need to give it the coordinates of your circle centre.

Comment: thank you. I did *AddArc()* and question is next can I make outline on this arc? I update post what I got so far.